# Calculate number of virtual pages per process

Tags: caching, virtual, virtual-memory, page-tables

I have 64 KB of pages, 4GB physical memory, and a 64-bit machine.

I learnt that 64-bit machines result in 256TB of virtual memory. If I had to calculate the # of virtual pages per process, would that simply be:

Total virtual memory/ Page size = 256TB/64KB = 4x10^9 pages?
I have read documentation online but I am not fully wrapping it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that means is that each process could theoretically have a logical address space of 2^64 bytes. Thus each process could theoretically have:

2^64/2^16 = 2^48 pages

In reality, it is effectively impossible for a process to have the maximum possible number of pages.

The number of pages is restricted by:

1. The division of the address space by mode.
2. Page file size
3. System parameters
4. process quotas